# How to delete a file dynamically in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

while deleting a file dynamically using c# it couldn't be deleted because its being used 
by another process but i have no other process which has been using this file.

```
foreach (string file in filess)
  {
   // FileInfo fi2 = new FileInfo(file);
  //  fi2.Delete();
      File.Delete(file);
  //  ii = 0;
   }
```

Comment: Perhaps it is used by your own process? For example you used a `FileStream` on it and forgot to dispose it.

Comment: did you close the fi2 object?

Comment: do you have it open in an editor?

Comment: I don't understand but my guess is that you forgot to close the file.

Comment: thank you @Chaos i have disposed FileStream still i am facing this problem.

Comment: @DDD i have closed the fi2 object

Comment: @araf apart of delete did you tried on renmaing or copying the file? if that works too? did you try it on Directory?

Comment: @araf, check a condition on it as well,its a good thing,if(!File.Exists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always make sure you close the streams you opened it:

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Create("C:\\1.txt"))
{
   // your code goes here

}// the object will be closed here
```

because if you don't put this `using` block it will cause a lot of bugs even if you closed it manually with `stream.Close();`

Answer (score 5):

Generally if it say that it is used by another process then you should consider this as true. To have sure you can verify this with this tool: [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)
It will tell you what process is locking file.

Answer (score 0):

If the File is in use you can't delete it, do the deletion in a try catch clauses. I would determine if the process using that file is your own app or some other process. You can use the [Unlocker](http://unlocker.softonic.de/) for that.

Comment: Thank you...The process using that file is in my own app.

Comment: Then provide please some more code or analyse your code and look where do access that file at any earlier point of time and check if you close the file properly after using it.

Comment: I have disposed and closed wherever i have opened the file that has to be access still i couldn't resolve it..

Comment: WCan you provide the code where you open and close this file before trying to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

This is How you can delete simply

```
        // File.Copy(@"‪C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\New.txt", @"D:\New.txt");

        string rootFolder = @"D:\";


        string authorsFile = "Gym.mdf";
        File.Delete(Path.Combine(rootFolder, authorsFile));


        string authorsFile2 = "Gym_log.ldf";
        File.Delete(Path.Combine(rootFolder, authorsFile2));
```